# Invoke method with an user defined class array parameter using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm attempting to write a method the executes a method by passing an array of a user defined class as arguments to the method using reflection.

```
Class[] argTypesList = new Class[] {String[].class, String[].class, MyClass[].class};       
Method methodToExecute = classToCall.getDeclaredMethod(“Method1”, argTypesList);
```

Method1 is:

```
Method1(String[] a, String[] b, MyClass[] myclass)
```

Here the third parameter is of user defined class array.

```
Class myClass= Class.forName("somepackage.MyClass");

argTypesList = new Class[] {String[].class, String[].class, myClass[]};
```

This gave below error

> error: '.class' expected

With `myClass[].class`, it gives

> cannot find symbol for myClass

Comment: The `m` in `MyClass` is uppercase. Did you miss that?

Comment: here, i just want to get the method using getDeclaredMethod with user defined class array. argTypesList = new Class[] {String[].class, String[].class, MyClass[]};

Comment: In your code you put myClass and in your comment you put MyClass. Java is case sensitive.

Comment: Vote to close. This is a simple typographical error.

Comment: Yes, i just gave the sample code , not actual code. Key point is how to get method of user defined class array.

Comment: Fix the compilation error in the code first and then ask the question.

Comment: You should post a [mcve] which reproduces the actual problem, not an approximation with typos and other errors.

Comment: I disagree. This is not a typographical error. OP meant to load a class dynamically and then call the method, which probably also expects a dynamic class array

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like this

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("...");
Class[] argTypesList = new Class[] { String[].class, String[].class, Array.newInstance(myClass, 0).getClass() };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by prefixing your class name with `[L` and using a suffix of `;`. Like so:

```
Class myClasses = Class.forName("[Lsomepackage.MyClass;");
argTypesList = new Class[]{String[].class, String[].class, myClasses};
```

Comment: Not reliable to hard code this. This behavior is not specified in JLS so they can change this at any time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lino !! it worked !!

Comment: @Rahul glad i could help you. Although consider the comment above yours from Jai. This is nowhere specified, so it might someday not work anymore